# phpmyadmin error when installing in arch linux

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i have tried installing phpmyadmin on arch linux but every time i open `localhost/phpmyadmin`,i get this text.

```
PHP 7.2.5+ is required.

Currently installed version is: ' . PHP_VERSION . '
'); } // phpcs:disable PSR1.Files.SideEffects define('PHPMYADMIN', true); // phpcs:enable require_once ROOT_PATH . 'libraries/constants.php'; /** * Activate autoloader */ if (! @is_readable(AUTOLOAD_FILE)) { die( '

File ' . AUTOLOAD_FILE . ' missing or not readable.
' . '

Most likely you did not run Composer to ' . '' . 'install library files.
' ); } require AUTOLOAD_FILE; global $route, $containerBuilder, $request; Common::run(); $dispatcher = Routing::getDispatcher(); Routing::callControllerForRoute($request, $route, $dispatcher, $containerBuilder);
```

i have installed php and this its version

```
PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2022 06:10:37) (NTS)
```

i have also tried following all the steps in arch documentation (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/phpMyAdmin)
but when i try to open the url(`localhost/phpmyadmin`),it outputs a blank page with no
body so i had to reset all the configs to default.help me out.thanks alot

Comment: Part of the text says: `Most likely you did not run Composer` ... did you try that? ... the command is `composer install`. Do that, and then retry PMA.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this issue,i reinstalled everything again,followed the steps in (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/phpMyAdmin) and in `/etc/php/php.ini`,uncommented the extension 'bz2 and mysqli'